# need a recursive CSV serializer for Django tastypie

Tags: python, django, csv, serialization, tastypie

I have created a simple GET only api for my Django application using tastypie. I need to deliver flat-tabular CSV data, but my database structure is normalized.  [Per the documentation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/serialization.html#implementing-your-own-serializer) I have implement a customized `Serializer` class with a `to_csv()` method as below.

```
def to_csv(self, data, options=None):
    options = options or {}
    data = self.to_simple(data, options)

    raw_data = StringIO.StringIO()
    writer = csv.writer(raw_data, quotechar="'", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)

    if "meta" in data.keys():#if multiple objects are returned
        objects = data.get("objects")
        writer.writerow(objects[0].keys())

        for object in objects:
            test = object.values()
            writer.writerow(test)
    else:
        writer.writerow(data.values())

    CSVContent=raw_data.getvalue()
    return CSVContent
```

This works great, except any resources get rendered by default as JSON (when I include `full = True` in the ModelResource ForeignKey specification), so I wind up with CSV data containing nested JSON data that looks like this.

```
foodID,foodName,related_details
1,"apricot","{'type':'fruit', 'cost':'medium'}"
2,"beef","{'type':'animal', 'cost':'high'}"
3,"celery","{'type':'vegetable', 'cost':'low'}"
```

My desired output is

```
foodID,foodName,type,cost
1,"apricot","fruit","medium"
2,"beef","animal","high"
3,"celery","vegetable","low"
```

I have an idea that I will need to apply my serializer recursively, and then to combine the results before writing to CSV, but have so far been unsuccessful.

Comment: are you looking for some code to convert your third element like: `line[:2] + eval(line[2]).values()` in a lambda function for instance?

Comment: that sounds promising, but I don't know anything about lambda functions. It would need to be general, in the sense that I don't want to assume that it is always 3rd element in the line that needs conversion, because different models have different foreign keys. So would need to first detect that it is JSON, then apply the conversion.

Comment: I think using a `DictWriter` would be better. I envisage out of order data.

Comment: @andrew-barr regarding your needs I think a lambda function won't match. I proposed you a more generic function in answer below which won't depend on position of the JSON string neither on the number of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def to_csv(self, data, options=None):
    options = options or {}
    data = self.to_simple(data, options)

    raw_data = StringIO.StringIO()
    first = True

    if "meta" in data.keys():#if multiple objects are returned
        objects = data.get("objects")

        for value in objects:
            test = {}
            self.flatten(value, test)
            if first:
                writer = csv.DictWriter(raw_data, test.keys(), quotechar="'", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
                writer.writeheader()
                writer.writerow(test)
                first=False
            else:
                writer.writerow(test)
    else:
        test = {}
        self.flatten(data, test)
        if first:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(raw_data, test.keys(), quotechar="'", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow(test)
            first=False
        else:
            writer.writerow(test)
    CSVContent=raw_data.getvalue()
    return CSVContent

def flatten(self, data, odict = {}):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        for value in data:
            self.flatten(value, odict)
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        for (key, value) in data.items():
            if not isinstance(value, (dict, list)):
                odict[key] = value
            else:
                self.flatten(value, odict)
```

Comment: I like the looks of this!  Thanks so much.  I will be sure to let you know how it works / accept the answer tomorrow when I give it a try.

Comment: This worked, after I tweaked it.  I submitted an edit of your answer that gets the header values (the dictionary key) in the first iteration after flattening.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function `to_list` on each line you have:

```
def to_list(line):
    idx = -1
    for i, l in enumerate(line):
        if type(l) is str and '{' in l and '}' in l:
            idx = i
            break
    if idx != -1:
        result = line[:idx] + eval(line[idx]).values() + line[idx+1:]
    else:
        result = line
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lst = [[1,"apricot","{'type':'fruit', 'cost':'medium'}"],
           ["beef","{'type':'animal', 'cost':'high'}", 3],
           ["meat", "sugar"],
           ["{'type':'car', 'cost':'nothing'}", "something"]]
    for line in lst:
        print to_list(line)
```

So for the following lists:

```
1, "apricot", "{'type':'fruit', 'cost':'medium'}"
"beef", "{'type':'animal', 'cost':'high'}", 3
"meat", "sugar"
"{'type':'car', 'cost':'nothing'}", "something"
```

You will get:

```
1, 'apricot', 'medium', 'fruit'
'beef', 'high', 'animal', 3
'meat', 'sugar'
'nothing', 'car', 'something'
```

As you can see it is not depending on the number of elements neither on the position of the JSON string.